# Enter the ID instead of selecting the name in LightSwitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I need the user to enter an ID instead of selecting the name. For example if you have 2 tables *customers* and *orders*, the user needs to enter the *customer id* in the order screen instead of selecting the name from the combo box.

How could I achieve this in LightSwitch?

Comment: It can be done. Add a screen shot or two so I have a starting point. So I know what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you would create a **parametrised query**, with a single *integer* parameter.

1. Add the new query to the screen (using *Add Data Item*), then drag it to
   the screen's control tree.
2. Add a string property to the screen (again using *Add Data Item*) that you can then have the user type the id into, & drag it to the screen's control tree.
3. Then just bind the query's parameter to the added string parameter, by clicking on the parameter (in the query on the left side of the screen designer), & setting the *Parameter Binding* value (in the *Properties* pane on the right side of the screen designer) to the name of the string property you added earlier. As you start typing, a list of choices will appear for you to choose from, or you can just type the whole thing yourself if you prefer.